# Disconnect a websocket in a separate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a webapp with a frontent code that connects to a websocket when a user clicks on a checkbox. When they click on it again and the checkbox checked value becomes false i want to disconnect the websocket. A user can have multiple items that are listed in a ul and each item has its own checkbox so they can connect multiple items to stream on the websocket. I collect the websockets in an array and index them. When a user clicks on the checkbox the client connects to the websocket fine. When a user clicks on the checkbox to disconnect I get the following error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

```js
  let tronToggle = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#tron-toggle"));
  tronToggle.forEach((item, index) => {
    let children = Array.from(item.children);
    let toolSet = {
      checkBox: children[0],
      map: children[1]
    };
    toolSet.checkBox.addEventListener("click", e => {
      loading();
      ws[index] = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000');
      ws[index].onopen=function(event){
        ws[index].send(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id);
      }
      if (e.target.checked === true) {
        toolSet.map.classList.toggle("hidden");
        setMarkerPosition(e, index);
      } else {
        toolSet.map.classList.toggle("hidden");
        ws[index].close();
        loaded();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

When I put the websocket.close() logic inside of the onopen (so after it starts) the websocket closes with no problem. How can I close it on uncheck?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you open a new WebSocket connection for each item? Browsers typically limit the number of concurrent connections to the same host (and this number differs per browser, too), so at some point you'll run into an issue there. Also, where is `index` coming from?

Comment: well because the web app is letting a user broadcast locations for different items. So when the page is built a user may have 5 items, when they click on the checkbox it broadcasts that item, so I want to be able to close the broadcast when they want one item to go 'offline'

Comment: updated code to show where index is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening an connection every time the checkbox is clicked. So first you check it and setup an connection. Then you click it again, create another connection and close it immediately.

```
toolSet.checkBox.addEventListener("click", e => { 
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
        loading();
        ws[index] = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000');
        ws[index].onopen=function(event){
            ws[index].send(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id);
        }
        toolSet.map.classList.toggle("hidden");
        setMarkerPosition(e, index);
    } else {
        toolSet.map.classList.toggle("hidden");
        ws[index].close();
        loaded();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup that was it.